# Between timeslot is available

Tags: php, datetime

The problem is that I can't really seems to figure out a way to ensure that it doesn't output ' is available' to a timeslot that is already used taken in the $events variable.

As for the output example you can see for 2015-11-18 10:00:00 to 2015-11-18 10:30:00 it claims that the slot is available, but this should not be available as there is an event at that timeslot.

Output example for code below:

> 2015-11-18 09:00:00 to 2015-11-18 09:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 09:30:00 to 2015-11-18 10:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 10:00:00 to 2015-11-18 10:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 10:30:00 to 2015-11-18 11:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 11:00:00 to 2015-11-18 11:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 11:30:00 to 2015-11-18 12:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 12:00:00 to 2015-11-18 12:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 12:30:00 to 2015-11-18 13:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 13:00:00 to 2015-11-18 13:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 13:30:00 to 2015-11-18 14:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 14:00:00 to 2015-11-18 14:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 14:30:00 to 2015-11-18 15:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 15:00:00 to 2015-11-18 15:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 15:30:00 to 2015-11-18 16:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 16:00:00 to 2015-11-18 16:30:00 is available

I use http://carbon.nesbot.com/ for the Carbon required in the top.

```
<?php
    require 'Carbon.php';
    use Carbon\Carbon;

    $schedule = [
        'start' => '2015-11-18 06:00:00',
        'end' => '2015-11-18 18:00:00',
    ];

    $start = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['start']));
    $end = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['end']));

    $minInterval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
    $reqInterval = new DateInterval('PT45M');

    $events = [
        [
            'created_at' => '2015-11-18 10:00:00',
            'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 13:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'created_at' => '2015-11-18 14:00:00',
            'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 16:00:00',
        ],
    ];

    function slotAvailable($from, $to, $events){
        foreach($events as $event){
            $eventStart = new DateTime($event['created_at']);
            $eventEnd = new DateTime($event['updated_at']);

            if(($from > $eventStart && $to < $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventEnd && $to > $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventStart && $to > $eventStart)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $minInterval, $end) as $slot){
        $to = $slot->copy()->add($reqInterval);

        echo $slot->toDateTimeString() . ' to ' . $to->toDateTimeString();

        if(slotAvailable($slot, $to, $events)){
            echo ' is available';
        }
        echo '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like if i added = to the first part of the if statement it fixed most of it, and I just added an extra check to the if statement if $to was over $schedule['end'], so it also fixed that problem.

The final code is this.

```
<?php
require 'Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

$schedule = [
    'start' => '2015-11-18 06:00:00',
    'end' => '2015-11-18 18:00:00',
];

$start = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['start']));
$end = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['end']));

$minInterval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$reqInterval = new DateInterval('PT45M');

$events = [
    [
        'created_at' => '2015-11-18 10:00:00',
        'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 13:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'created_at' => '2015-11-18 14:00:00',
        'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 16:00:00',
    ],
];

function slotAvailable($from, $to, $events, $workEnd){
    foreach($events as $event){
        $eventStart = new DateTime($event['created_at']);
        $eventEnd = new DateTime($event['updated_at']);

        if(($from >= $eventStart && $to <= $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventEnd && $to > $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventStart && $to > $eventStart) || ($to > $workEnd)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $minInterval, $end) as $slot){
    $to = $slot->copy()->add($reqInterval);
    $workEnd = $schedule['end'];

    echo $slot->toDateTimeString() . ' to ' . $to->toDateTimeString();

    if(slotAvailable($slot, $to, $events, $workEnd)){
        echo ' is available';
    }
    echo '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition in `slotAvailable` is wrong: you have to include the start and end of the intervals with `>=` or `<=`. Also, I think it can be simplified:

```
if ($eventStart <= $from && $eventEnd >= $to) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still seems to give me a problem if I change $reqInterval = new DateInterval('PT30M'); to $reqInterval = new DateInterval('PT45M');